# refresh uitableview on button click getting data from webservice

Tags: ios, uitableview, refresh, reload

I am trying to implement a functionality such that when a refresh button on the uitabbar is clicked, a webservice is called which returns certain data. the data is stored in sqlite db and then rendered on a tableview. My problem is that when new data is fetched from the service, the db gets updated, but the updated records to not show in the tableview immediately. i have to restart the application to see the updated records. Below is my code that is called on tapping the reload button:

Updated Code:

```
-(void)get_vrns {
    NSLog(@"Refreshing...");
    NSString *delete = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM VRN"];
    NSString *insert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO VRN ('VRNumber') VALUES ('%@')", @"LEC8-9436"];
    insert = @"INSERT INTO VRN ('VRNumber') VALUES ('LEC-876'); INSERT INTO VRN ('VRNumber') VALUES ('AAA-564');INSERT INTO VRN ('VRNumber') VALUES ('ABD-908'); INSERT INTO VRN ('VRNumber') VALUES ('AHF-540');";

    char *err;
    if (sqlite3_exec(db, [delete UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if (sqlite3_exec(db, [insert UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_close(db);
            NSAssert(0, @"Could not update table");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Table updated");
        }
    }
    else {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Could not delete records");
    }
    [self.vrnTable reloadData];
    NSString *select = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT VRNumber FROM VRN"];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [select UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            char *vrn = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
            NSString *vrnStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:vrn];

            NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", vrnStr];
            [_entries addObject:str];
        }
    }
    else {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: Because %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", self.entries);
}
```

Comment: show reloadData method

Comment: its a class method in uitableview

Comment: try calling [vrnTable reloadData] rather than thread

Comment: already did that. doesn't work

Comment: Does "table updated" get logged?

Comment: yes. it does get updated

Answer (score 0):

Would like to know where are you storing data for displaying in tableview. I mean we usually use NSArray for storing data of tableview, using which in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexpath: method we fetch data from array and place it on cell. Are you updating that array from sqlite table or whatever variable you are using.

Updated Code:

```
-(void)get_vrns {
    NSLog(@"Refreshing...");
    NSString *delete = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM VRN"];
    NSString *insert = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO VRN ('VRNumber') VALUES ('%@')", @"LEC8-9436"];
    insert = @"INSERT INTO VRN ('VRNumber') VALUES ('LEC-876'); INSERT INTO VRN ('VRNumber') VALUES ('AAA-564');INSERT INTO VRN ('VRNumber') VALUES ('ABD-908'); INSERT INTO VRN ('VRNumber') VALUES ('AHF-540');";

char *err;
if (sqlite3_exec(db, [delete UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) == SQLITE_OK) {
    if (sqlite3_exec(db, [insert UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSAssert(0, @"Could not update table");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Table updated");
    }
}
else {
    sqlite3_close(db);
    NSAssert(0, @"Could not delete records");
}

[self.entries removeAllObjects];

NSString *select = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT VRNumber FROM VRN"];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [select UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        char *vrn = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
        NSString *vrnStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:vrn];

        NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", vrnStr];
        [_entries addObject:str];
    }
}
else {
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error: Because %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
NSLog(@"%@", self.entries);

[self.vrnTable reloadData];

}
```

Comment: yes. I am updating the data from sqlite. What I want to do is that on tapping on the refresh button, the tableview gets clear, a service is called and the table is filled with the latest data.

Comment: @HassanZaheer call the tableView reloadData function at the end of the method after fetching data from sqlite into your _entries variable. You are calling reloaddata before entries coming into your variable.

Comment: this only adds the new data to the table. I have to remove the previous data before populating the tableview with the new data.

Comment: got it. had to remove all objects from array before addding new ones.

Comment: Yes to show only new data, we need to remove all the previous object from array and load it with new ones. Please tick the answer as right if you think it was correct. Enjoy coding.